# How to calculate the margin of error if the sample size is not given?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

The mean and standard deviation of a random sample of $n$ measurements equal 
33.9 and 3.3 respectively.

Construct a 95% confidence interval for $n = 100$.

Hence I am trying to calculate margin of error and then use that to derive the sample size and then to construct my diagram. But the information given seems not to be enough.

Comment: Ehh... can you work the term $n$ into your answer?

Comment: But n is not given.They say it is n-100 which is confusing.

Comment: I bet that's meant to say "n=100"

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a continuous data question

Standard dev=33.9
Conf.level = 0.95
z value = 1.96
Margin of Error =

ES = |P1-P0|/^P0(1-P0) is the formula for the E (margin of error)